# PHPUnit how to test a Repository?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, phpunit

I have a group of Repository classes I'd like to test. All Eloquent methods are called in these classes, however I am unsure on how to proceed. The only thing that needs to be tested, is that the methods return the right data type. I want to be sure that `getByEmail($email)` for example actually returns a `User` object, *but I don't care about the implementation details.*

Every example I see tells you to inject the model in to the Repository class and mock it, then you can proceed by having that Mock expect very specific method calls. Is this the correct approach? Because it seems to me that would be forcing the developer to use very specific methods when building the Eloquent query.

Here's an example:

```
class UserRepository {
    public function __construct(User user) { ... }

    public function getByEmail(string $email) : ?User {
        $this->user->where('email', $email)->first();
    }
}
```

For the test with Mock to work I have to do:

```
class myTest {
    public function testMethodReturnsUserObject() {
        $user = Mockery::mock(User::class);

        $repo = new UserRepository($user);
        
        // now, if a developer changes the eloquent method calls, this will fail.
        $user->shouldReceive('where->first')->andReturn($user);

        $this->assertEquals($user, $repo->getByEmail('joe.bloggs@acme.com'));
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I should do to  test that my method does indeed return a User object, without forcing the developer to use exactly one `where()` method, and one `first()` method in this example. What if the developer needs to instead make it `->select()->where()->where()->firstOrFail()` . Now the unit test will break, even though it really shouldn't care about this, and only that the method returns a User.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the implementation `getByEmail` of the `UserRepository` class?

Comment: Its already there, It's the only method in the UserRepository class. This is not real code, its pseudo, but it has all the same features of my real Repository, which contains maybe 10 or 11 methods.

Answer (score 3):

Skip unit testing this, and focus on integration tests with the database. Since that's your primary functionality you want to assert: "Does this repository return the record(s) I expect?"

```php
public function testMethodReturnsUserObject(): void
{
    // Note: old factory() syntax; Laravel 8 is different
    $expectedUser = factory(User::class)->create([
        'id' => 1,
        'email' => 'user@example.com',
    ]);

    $repo = new UserRepository(new User());

    $actualUser = $repo->getByEmail('user@example.com');

    self::assertNotEmpty($actualUser);
    self::assertSame(1, $actualUser->id);

    self::assertNull($repo->getByEmail('notfound@example.com'));
}
```

[Lots of great docs to assist in database testing.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing)

Comment: I think this is where it's clear how little I understand about Unit Testing. Why would I not do my test? and why would you do an integration test? What's the purpose of writing a record to the database to check if the repository fetches it. Would I then have to delete it again because this is running on live data?